# Converting to Java Model-View-Controller pattern

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller

I have a "Add & Display" java program, organised into classes according to each screen the program shows (E.g. Menu, DisplayPatients, AddPatients, etc).

Now I need to convert this to an MVC pattern for ym school project. While I understand in theory what an MVC does, I have no idea how to segregate my 7 current classes into 4 classes: the Main, Model, View, and Controller.

I'm really lost as I have no idea what to put where.

Appreciate your help!!

Comment: You're not alone.  Most people don't know how to do this.

Comment: Try to "push-up" common elements from each class -- e.g. Menu, AddPatients. etc. Try to create lean models, smart controllers and dumb views.

Comment: (Understand that MVC is only a theoretical ideal, rarely actually implemented, and often attempts to implement it result in some terribly contorted code.  Pay lip service to the scheme if necessary to pass your course, but don't get married to it.)

Comment: OP, please consider accepting the answer that was the most helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main benefits of the Model-View-Controller design pattern is that, like the State or Strategy patterns, you can swap out classes with the same interface to get different behaviors. With MVC, this typically turns into swapping out different Models, Views, or Controllers while keeping the other two components.

In your program, it looks like you should have different Views, all implementing a common interface, for each "display". The Model should handle data like lists of patients, and the Controller should act on the user input it gets from the Views (i.e. the Controller should handle what is commonly referred to as the "business logic" of the program).

So, to give one example, the AddPatients display might be turned into a specific View and some Controller logic, which would use some sort of `addPatient()` method in the Model.

Answer (score 0):

I've really only dealt with MVC from a web application perspective (Spring MVC / Struts).

The way we do it for webapps would be:

Model: Anything to do with your application's problem domain. I.E, independent of the user interface.

View: JSP's, html, Velocity Templates, Jasper Reports, anything that "present" the model

Controller: Handles UI commands and sends commands to the model to update or retrieve state.  This can include "front" controllers that delegate to others, like a DispatcherServlet or ActionServlet.

It's really simple to separate your view.  For Java EE webapps, these could be JSPs. The OPPOSITE of this would be using a servlet that renders html (a JSP is really a servlet too, but you get the point). For an Android app, they could possibly be your XML view layouts.

After you have your view, you can create a controller that is a layer between your "business" classes and the view itself.  For example, it could respond to web requests or respond to click events.

Then you just encapsulate your business logic into classes your controller delegates to (so it isn't tied to your UI).

Another pattern used here is the concept of a "UI bean".  In the webapp world, this would be a form bean.  Here, the controller deals with the view by means of a javabean containing values that the view can see/update.  The controller validates this form and converts it to a request your model processes.  Again, this is used to separate your UI from your business logic.